# Confidence interval for mean using t-distribution (unknown pop.variance). Is the following statement true or false?

Tags: statistics

This is from an A-Level statistics paper.

We are the given the lengths of 10 components and asked to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean. We are given that the lengths are normally distributed with unknown population variance.
The confidence interval is correctly calculated (using a t-distribution) as 133.78 to 135.24

State whether the following statements are

A = Definitely True

B = Almost certainly True

C = Almost certainly untrue; or

D = Definitely untrue

Statement 2 (I know the answers to the other statements)

A random sample of size 10 is to be taken from the population. The probability that the mean of this sample will like in the interval 133.78 to 135.24 is 0.95.

I thought the answer would be B, Almost certainly true. But apparently it is C (untrue). The very brief answer given in the book says this is because we are dealing with unknown population variance. Can someone explain this in a bit more detail?

Thanks

Comment: If you construct a confidence interval you need to know either the variance of the population $(\sigma ^2)$ or the variance of the sample ( $s^2$). You don´t have both values. Thus you cannot know or proof, if the confidence interval is constructed right.

Comment: The sample variance is known. It can be calculated since the length of the 10 components are given.